# Vowpal Wabbit python wrapper empty prediction file

Tags: vowpalwabbit

The prediction file when called from pyvw wrapper is empty.
For example, I am doing something like,

```
vw = pyvw.vw(" -i cb.model --cb_explore 50 --cover 10 -p prediction.txt")
ex = vw.example(" | label label2")
vw.predict(ex)
vw.finish()
ex.finish()
```

This creates prediction.txt but does not write anything to it.

I would greatly appreciate any guidance.

Thank you!

Comment: I thought that the purpose of Python wrapper is that you don't need to communicate via files. You should extract the predictions with the API calls directly. That said, I agree `pyvw.vw` should produce a warning/exception if you supply `-p` among the arguments.

Answer (score 1):

This snippet might help you:

```
from vowpalwabbit import pyvw

def to_vw(clf, text, str_label):
    vw_example = str('{} |f {} '.format(str_label, text))
    return clf.example(vw_example)

clf = vw = pyvw.vw(
    loss_function='logistic', oaa=2,
    link='logistic', raw_predictions='output.txt'
)

ex = to_vw(clf, 'I like vowpal wabbit. But not that much.', '1')
clf.learn(ex)
clf.predict(ex, labelType=pyvw.pylibvw.vw.lMulticlass)
```

You should have the probabilities written in `output.txt` file.